# Extracting avg. nodal stresses from odb file and nodeset using python

Tags: abaqus

What I am trying to do:

- I want to extract nodal displacements (U2) and stresses (S22), which have been transformed into a local coordinate system, in order to animate their variation with each frame of a given analysis step.
- Extracting history outputs and the nodal displacement field is OK. However, getting the stresses seems more cumbersome.

[Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoMlf.png)

Problems:

- The NODAL specified stress field is not node averaged. How do I obtain these?
- The nodal stress output seems a bit random even though it has been specified through subsetregion = nodeSet. It looks like I am only accessing half of the non-averaged nodal stresses along the path nodeset which I have defined.

I have posted the entire script, but where it goes wrong is from the for loop over frames in the step: for frameNo in range(0,nFrames):
Any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    odb = openOdb(path = "PostJob.odb")



  partName = odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys()
    
    print('AVAILABLE PARTS AND PART NAMES IN THE MODEL', partName)
    
    nSets = len(odb.rootAssembly.instances[partName[0]].nodeSets.keys())
    nSetKeys = odb.rootAssembly.instances[partName[0]].nodeSets.keys()

    print('AVAILABLE SETS IN THE PART ',partName[0],'sets',nSetKeys)
    print('NO. OF SETS IN PART INSTANCE',nSets)
    
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # FORCE-DISPLACEMENT CURVES ----------------------------------------------
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    # Extract U1 and RF1 from the history output
    U1data  = odb.steps['CZ Analysis'].historyRegions['Node ASSEMBLY.1'].historyOutputs['U1'].data
    RF1data = odb.steps['CZ Analysis'].historyRegions['Node ASSEMBLY.1'].historyOutputs['RF1'].data
    
    
    # The data is in the form of tuples, which we will convert to np. arrays instead.
    U1data=np.asarray(U1data)
    RF1data = np.array(RF1data)

    # Plotting the force-displacement curve
    plt.plot(U1data[:,1],RF1data[:,1])
    
    plt.ylabel('Force: RF1 in [N]')
    plt.xlabel('Displacement: U1 in [mm]')
    plt.xlim((0,2))
    plt.title('Force-Displacement Curve')
    
    #plt.show()
 
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # INTERFACE TRACTIONS ----------------------------------------------------
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    # Access the test node path and create a node path in the visulalization module
    
    alpha = 10.0*math.pi/180 # with X-axis
    
    # Perform a coordinate transformation on the nodal coordinates by using the transformation matrix T
    R = np.array([[math.cos(alpha),-math.sin(alpha),0],
                  [math.sin(alpha), math.cos(alpha),0],
                  [              0,               0,1]])
    # T = [cos alpha, -sin alpha, 0; sin alpha, cos alpha, 0; 0, 0, 1] 
    print(R)
    
    e1 = np.array([1,0,0])
    e2 = np.array([0,1,0])
    e3 = np.array([0,0,1])
    
    e1p = np.dot(R, e1.transpose())
    e2p = np.dot(R, e2.transpose())
    e3p = np.dot(R, e3.transpose())
    
    
    origin=[0,0,0]
    
    #plt.figure()
    origin = np.array([0, 0, 0]) 
    #plt.quiver([e1p[0],e2p[0],e3p[0]],[e1p[1],e2p[1],e3p[1]], color=['r','g','b'],scale=21)
   
    # Create a new coordinate system
    coordSys = odb.rootAssembly.DatumCsysByThreePoints(name='Bond-CSYS', coordSysType=CARTESIAN, 
                                                        origin=(0.0,0.0,0.0), 
                                                        point1=tuple(e1p),
                                                        point2=tuple(e2p))
    
    # Extract the node set and stress field of the node path.
    instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['ADHESIVE']
    
    bondPath = instance.nodeSets['MIDNODESET']
     
    allBondPathNodes = bondPath.nodes[0:-1]
    
    nNodes = len(bondPath.nodes)
    
    print('NUMBER OF NODES IN BONDLINE PATH FOUND FROM MIDNODESET', nNodes)
    
    nodeCoord = np.zeros([3,nNodes])


    
    # Transform the coordinates into the local coordinates of the bondline
    jj = -1
    for node in allBondPathNodes:
        jj += 1
        nodeCoord[0,jj] = node.coordinates[0]
        nodeCoord[1,jj] = node.coordinates[1]
        nodeCoord[2,jj] = node.coordinates[2]

    # plt.figure()
    # plt.plot(nodeCoord[0,:],nodeCoord[1,:])


    # Transform the coordinates and determine the 
    transNodeCoord = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(R),nodeCoord)

    # Test coordinates by plotting the line
    #plt.plot(transNodeCoord[0,:],transNodeCoord[1,:])
    
    
    # EXTRACT RELEVANT FIELDS ------
    
    # Create a for loop to loop over the number of frames in the odb:

    
    step  = odb.steps['CZ Analysis']
    
    nFrames = len(step.frames)
    
    print("No. of Frames", nFrames)
    
    # Initialize arrays outside for loop
    U11  = np.zeros([nNodes,nFrames])
    U22  = np.zeros([nNodes,nFrames])
    t11  = np.zeros([nNodes,nFrames])
    t22  = np.zeros([nNodes,nFrames])
    t12  = np.zeros([nNodes,nFrames])

    for frameNo in range(0,nFrames):
    
        # Current frame no in analysis step 'CZ Analysis'
        frame = step.frames[frameNo]
    
        # Get the stress and displacement field for the current frame
        stressField = frame.fieldOutputs['S']
        displacement = frame.fieldOutputs['U']
        
        # Transform the displacement and stress field to local coordinate system
        transfStressField = stressField.getTransformedField(datumCsys=coordSys)
        transfDisplacementField = displacement.getTransformedField(datumCsys = coordSys)
        
        # Extract nodal field results for subset region = bondPath
        pathStressField = transfStressField.getSubset(region=bondPath,position=NODAL)
        pathDisplacementField = transfDisplacementField.getSubset(region=bondPath)
        
        # Extract displacement field U1 component
        dispU1   = pathDisplacementField.getScalarField(componentLabel='U1')
        dispU2   = pathDisplacementField.getScalarField(componentLabel='U2')

        # Loop over nodal values and append them to np.array
        jj = -1

        for u,v, stress in zip(dispU1.values, dispU2.values,transfStressField.values):
            jj += 1
            
            U11[jj][frameNo]  = u.data
            U22[jj][frameNo]  = v.data
            t11[jj][frameNo]  = stress.data[0]
            t22[jj][frameNo]  = stress.data[1]
            t12[jj][frameNo]  = stress.data[3]
            #print('Displacement node label', u.nodeLabel,v.nodeLabel,'Stress object node label', stress.nodeLabel)
            #print("Node Label", v.nodeLabel, "Displacement Value", v.data,"S11",stress.data[0], "S22",stress.data[1],"S12",stress.data[3])
        
        #print('POSITION: ', v.position, "Coordinate", node.coordinates, "Displacement Value", v.data)
        
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    axs[1].set_xlabel('x-coordinate')

    
    def animate(i):
        axs[0].clear()
        axs[1].clear()
        #ax.plot(transNodeCoord[0,:],t22[:,i]) # stresses are discontinous because they are specified at nodes
        #ax.set_title('Displacement: U2', 'Frame No:',i)
        axs[0].set_title('Displacement: U2 , Frame No: {}'.format(i))
        axs[0].plot(np.flip(transNodeCoord[0,:]),U22[:,i])  # Displacements are continous, but look weird.-
        axs[1].set_title('Traction: T22 , Frame No: {}'.format(i))
        axs[1].plot(np.flip(transNodeCoord[0,:]),t22[:,i])
        #ax.set_xlim([0,transNodeCoord[-1,:]])
    
    
    # Create animation
    
    ani1 = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=32,interval=500,blit=False,repeat=True)
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Abaqus calculates stress at integration points located inside the 3D element (number and position [depend on the element type](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEELMRefMap/simaelm-r-3delem.htm)). After the stress is calculated it is extrapolated to the nodes of the element.

Thus, each node would get a value from each element sharing that node. If the meshing is not fine enough such an interpolation could result in high differences in node values obtained from adjacent elements. Abaqus by default [averages these values](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAECAERefMap/simacae-c-resconceptaverage.htm#:%7E:text=Abaqus%2FCAE%20averages%20values%20at,element%20sets%20or%20display%20groups.) for visualization purposes.

For your task, you can export values at nodes and perform averaging by yourself. Or use results obtained at the element centroid/at integration points and pair these values with the corresponding coordinate. After obtaining Streess vs X-coordinate and Strain vs X-coordinate data sets you can interplate first or second so X-coordinates of both are matching.